# apt-get update fails with 404's

Tags: apt, updates

I recently started getting 404's on apt-get update, following no particularly interesting change on my part that I'm aware of.

```
dh@ubuntu:/etc/apt$ sudo apt-get update
Ign file:  InRelease
Ign file:  InRelease                                                    
Ign file:  InRelease                                                     
Get:1 file:  Release.gpg [198 B]                                               
Get:2 file:  Release.gpg [181 B]                                               
Get:3 file:  Release.gpg [181 B]                                               
Get:4 file:  Release [196 B]                                                   
Get:5 file:  Release [191 B]                                                   
Get:6 file:  Release [195 B]                                                   
Ign file:  Translation-en_US                                                   
Ign file:  Translation-en                                                      
Ign file:  Translation-en_US                                                   
Ign file:  Translation-en                                                      
Ign file:  Translation-en_US                                                   
Ign file:  Translation-en                                                      
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease                      
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                       
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease                              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages            
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                    
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release                                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages        
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages         
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Sources                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages      
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages       
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner armhf Packages                 
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner i386 Packages                  
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages              
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Translation-en                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages          
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages        
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main armhf Packages                        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.152 80]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages     
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en 
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                         
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main armhf Packages     
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages               
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages               
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main armhf Packages            
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted armhf Packages      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe armhf Packages        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse armhf Packages      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main armhf Packages          
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted armhf Packages    
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe armhf Packages      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse armhf Packages    
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main armhf Packages                    
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe armhf Packages                
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted armhf Packages              
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse armhf Packages              
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                 
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US           
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US           
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US             
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/multiverse/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/multiverse/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

My /etc/apt/sources.list contains:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

It's a bit strange to me that the update looks like it's trying to hit ARM sources, given I'm on x86:

```
dh@ubuntu:/etc/apt$ arch
x86_64
```

Possibly that's related to the fact I just cross-compiled & installed JetPack on a Jetson TK1 (which is ARMHF) from this Ubuntu machine? Wild speculation there.

Indeed the missing remote files really are missing, but, uh, how did I go wrong and how do I get back...?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Dan

Comment: Please add the outputs of `dpkg --print-architecture` and `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system has had the armhf architecture added to it as a foreign architecture.

```
dpkg --remove-architecture armhf
```

should clear the problem.  Do an "apt-get update" afterwards and the problem should be gone.

Comment: Indeed so. First I had to `sudo apt-get remove .*:armhf`, after which dpkg removed the foreign architecture. Thanks greatly.