# Depends: gimagereader-gtk but it is not going to be installed

Tags: package-management

I would like to install [gimagereader](https://github.com/manisandro/gImageReader) and I tried with

```
:~$ sudo apt-get install gimagereader 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gimagereader : Depends: gimagereader-gtk but it is not going to be installed                                                                                                                             
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

:~$ sudo apt-get install gimagereader-gtk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gimagereader-gtk is already the newest version.
```

as well as the commands in https://askubuntu.com/a/944282/402358 which did nothing.

Also:

```
:~$ sudo apt-mark showhold
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://linux-packages.resilio.com/resilio-sync/deb/ resilio-sync/non-free armhf Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/linux-packages.resilio.com_resilio-sync_deb_dists_resilio-sync_non-free_binary-armhf_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

Also, my source.list is

```
# deb cdrom:[Kubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140416.1)]/ trusty main multiverse restricted universe

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb [arch=amd64] http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src [arch=amd64] http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb [arch=amd64] http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src [arch=amd64] http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb [arch=amd64] http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src [arch=amd64] http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb [arch=amd64] http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src [arch=amd64] http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb [arch=amd64] http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src [arch=amd64] http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb [arch=amd64] http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src [arch=amd64] http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb [arch=amd64] http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src [arch=amd64] http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb [arch=amd64] http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src [arch=amd64] http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb [arch=amd64] http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src [arch=amd64] http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb [arch=amd64] http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src [arch=amd64] http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb-src [arch=amd64] http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb [arch=amd64] http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src [arch=amd64] http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main

### For R:
# deb [arch=amd64] http://cran.r-mirror.de/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/
# deb-src [arch=amd64] http://cran.r-mirror.de/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/
# deb [arch=amd64] http://ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/misc/cran/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/
# deb [arch=amd64] http://cran.es.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty
# deb [arch=amd64] http://www.stats.bris.ac.uk/R/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/
# deb [arch=amd64] http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/
deb [arch=amd64] http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/

### For R-Extras:
# deb [arch=amd64] http://orange.biolab.si/debian squeeze main
# deb-src [arch=amd64] http://orange.biolab.si/debian squeeze main

### For the KDE Widget "Concise":
deb [arch=amd64] http://ppa.launchpad.net/bytr/concise/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src [arch=amd64] http://ppa.launchpad.net/bytr/concise/ubuntu trusty main
# Run: $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bytr/concise; sudo apt-get install concise

### For Virtualbox:
# deb [arch=amd64] http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib
# deb-src [arch=amd64] http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib

### For Dropbox:
# deb [arch=amd64] http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src [arch=amd64] http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu trusty main

### For Resilio:
deb [arch=armhf] http://linux-packages.resilio.com/resilio-sync/deb resilio-sync non-free
```

Also:

```
:~$ sudo apt-cache policy gimagereader
gimagereader:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.1.2-1~trustyppa1
  Version table:
     3.1.2-1~trustyppa1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/sandromani/gimagereader/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

What can I do? I am using Kubuntu 14.4.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64845/discussion-on-question-by-make42-depends-gimagereader-gtk-but-it-is-not-going-t).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apt-get process for loading the correct version of `gimagereader` seems not to be working properly from the [ppa on launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~sandromani/+archive/ubuntu/gimagereader/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=trusty) - you are loading new versions of the `gimagereader-gtk` (3.2.3) and attempting to load an older version of `gimagereader` (3.1.2)

I would encourage you to perhaps report this as a bug against the PPA, but *as a work-around* you could directly download the deb files required and install them manually:

[gimagereader-common_3.2.3-1~trustyppa1_all.deb](https://launchpad.net/~sandromani/+archive/ubuntu/gimagereader/+files/gimagereader-common_3.2.3-1~trustyppa1_all.deb)

[gimagereader-dbg_3.2.3-1~trustyppa1_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/~sandromani/+archive/ubuntu/gimagereader/+files/gimagereader-dbg_3.2.3-1~trustyppa1_amd64.deb)

[gimagereader-gtk_3.2.3-1~trustyppa1_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/~sandromani/+archive/ubuntu/gimagereader/+files/gimagereader-gtk_3.2.3-1~trustyppa1_amd64.deb)

[gimagereader-qt_3.2.3-1~trustyppa1_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/~sandromani/+archive/ubuntu/gimagereader/+files/gimagereader-qt_3.2.3-1~trustyppa1_amd64.deb)

Move these 4 files into a directory, and `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` to install them.  You may need to load `tesseract-ocr` independantly

Comment: This actually worked, very nice!

Comment: @Make42 Sorry it took me so long...

Comment: All this back and forth however messed up my system "real good": https://askubuntu.com/questions/951662/package-management-system-is-messed-up-regarding-architecture

Comment: I suspect that it's the armhf architecture that you added for resilio... [https://askubuntu.com/questions/708056/apt-get-update-fails-with-404s](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708056/apt-get-update-fails-with-404s)