# Package management system is messed up regarding architecture

Tags: apt, package-management, architecture

I think I messed up something in my package system. I tried to get to some sort of "basic" state, I used https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/generate.php to get me a new source.list. I renamed `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d.save` to have that out of the way. But now when I

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I am getting a lot of messages like

```
Err http://download.virtualbox.org trusty/contrib armhf Packages               
  404  Not Found [IP: 2.20.143.5 80]
Ign http://download.virtualbox.org trusty/contrib Translation-en               
Ign http://download.virtualbox.org trusty/contrib Translation-de
```

or 
    W: Failed to fetch http://update.yuuguu.com/repositories/apt/dists/hardy/multiverse/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2.20.143.5 80]

My source.list is
    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    #                            OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS                             #
    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

```
###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Partner Repo
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

###### Ubuntu Extras Repo
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#                           UNOFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS                            #
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#


###### 3rd Party Binary Repos

#### Banshee PPA - https://edge.launchpad.net/~banshee-team
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 6E80C6B7
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/banshee-team/ppa/ubuntu trusty main

#### Daniil's Bash Video Download - http://daniil.it
## Run this command: wget -q -O - http://dano.cu.cc/1Aci9Qp | sudo apt-key add - && sudo apt-get update
deb http://repo.daniil.it lenny main

#### Daniil's repo - http://daniil.it
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keys.gnupg.net 72B97FD1D9672C93 && sudo apt-get update
deb http://repo.daniil.it lenny main

#### Dropbox - http://dropbox.com
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 5044912E
deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/ trusty main

#### Gimp PPA - https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/gimp
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 614C4B38
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu trusty main

#### GNOME3 Extra Apps PPA - https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3B1510FD
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu trusty main

#### Google Chrome Browser - http://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/
## Run this command: wget -q https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub -O- | sudo apt-key add -
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main

#### Google Earth - http://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/
## Run this command: wget -q https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub -O- | sudo apt-key add -
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable main

#### JDownloader PPA - https://launchpad.net/~jd-team
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 6A68F637
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jd-team/jdownloader/ubuntu trusty main

#### Kubuntu Backports PPA - https://edge.launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/backports
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8AC93F7A
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu trusty main

#### Kubuntu Beta Backports PPA - https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/beta
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8AC93F7A
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/beta/ubuntu trusty main

#### Kubuntu Updates PPA - https://edge.launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ppa
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8AC93F7A
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/ppa/ubuntu trusty main 

#### LibreOffice PPA - http://www.documentfoundation.org/download/
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 1378B444
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu trusty main

#### MongoDB - http://www.mongodb.org/
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen

#### Opera - http://www.opera.com/
## Run this command: sudo wget -O - http://deb.opera.com/archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
deb http://deb.opera.com/opera/ stable non-free

#### Oracle Java (JDK) Installer PPA - http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EEA14886
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main

#### ownCloud Desktop Client - http://owncloud.org/
## Run this command: wget -q http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:ownCloud:community/xUbuntu_14.04/Release.key -O- | sudo apt-key add -
deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/community/xUbuntu_14.04/ /

#### Pidgin PPA - http://pidgin.im
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A1F196A8
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu trusty main

#### Steam for Linux - http://store.steampowered.com/about/
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F24AEA9FB05498B7
deb [arch=i386] http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam

#### Tor: anonymity online - http://www.torproject.org/
## Run this command: gpg --keyserver subkeys.pgp.net --recv 886DDD89 && gpg --export --armor 886DDD89  | sudo apt-key add -
deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org trusty main

#### VirtualBox - http://www.virtualbox.org
## Run this command: wget -q http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib

#### WebUpd8 PPA - http://www.webupd8.org/
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4C9D234C
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu trusty main

#### WebUpd8 Unstable PPA - http://www.webupd8.org/
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EEA14886
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/unstable/ubuntu trusty main

#### Wine PPA - https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa/
## Run this command:  sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F9CB8DB0
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu trusty main

#### X Updates PPA - https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates/
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys AF1CDFA9
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu trusty main

#### Xorg Edgers PPA - https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8844C542  
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu trusty main

#### Yuuguu - http://yuuguu.com
deb http://update.yuuguu.com/repositories/apt hardy multiverse
```

What did I do wrong?

I am having a amd64 system with Kubuntu 14.4.

Comment: Please note the line `W: Failed to fetch http://update.yuuguu.com/repositories/apt/dists/hardy/multiverse/binary-armhf/Packages 404 Not Found [IP: 2.20.143.5 80]` indicates that you are both looking for `armhf` packages, and packages from the Hardy distrubution (very old)

Comment: @CharlesGreen: Got it. But how do I solve it? I commented all those source lines which are not "trust". So what now? I am still getting lots of errors where and how do I deal with the armhf issue? It's not in the sources.list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by following https://askubuntu.com/a/708106/402358 and doing

```
dpkg --remove-architecture armhf
```